# How to force to change some method when new property is added to class

Tags: c#

I have the following issue 
Here is third party class which we are used(so i cannot change it)

```
public class ThirdPartyEmployee
{
    public string F_Name { get; set; }
    public string L_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date_of_birth { get; set; }
    public string Telephone1 { get; set; }
    public string Telephone2 { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }

    //..... and so on
}
```

Also we have our own smaller and better Employee class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileTelephone { get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes we need to convert third party class to our own. There is extension method for it

```
public static class ThirdPartyExtensions
{
    public static Employee ConvertTo(this ThirdPartyEmployee thirdPartyEmployee)
    {
        var result = new Employee();

        result.FirstName = thirdPartyEmployee.F_Name;
        result.LastName = thirdPartyEmployee.L_Name;
        result.MobileTelephone = thirdPartyEmployee.Telephone1;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now about the issue. **If somebody consider to add some other properties to Employee class he\she can forget to change ConvertTo method. How we can avoid it ?** Ideally i would like to have some compilation errors ... 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: That can typically be done with a unit test.

Comment: @EliArbel. Wow. It seems a little bit complicated solution ... Can you provide some link which can help me ?

Comment: @L-Four Unit test for old code(without new property in Employee class) will not detect that new property is not set after convertTo method

Comment: Well, unit test need to be up to date after every change, if you don't do that then you have other problems and developers need training :)

Comment: How is `Employee` used elsewhere? Is it feasible for it to be turned into a *wrapper* for `ThirdPartyEmployee`? Either directly, or by being an abstract base for two classes - one being the wrapper, the other being the unwrapped alternative?

Comment: Automapper and unit tests. Copy Constructor/ CoI couples the classes and since they're third party this is bad IMO.

Comment: We have checkbox on UI which means "get data from third party service". Often it is unchecked so we cannot create `Employee` class as wrapper for `ThirdpartyEmployee`. Also we cannot create base abstract class for them because i haven't access to `ThirsPartyEmployee`

Comment: No, I meant you have `abstract class Employee` and then `NormalEmployee : Employee` and `WrappedEmployee: Employee`. One is the wrapper, the other is normal, but most of the rest of your system continues to just work against `Employee`. Which means that as properties are added and need to be accessed, they have to be added as `abstract` to the `Employee` base class - and the compiler will mostly cajole you along to correct implementations.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Thanks for suggestion. I will think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not create a compilation error with standard means. There may be Visual Studio plugins that allow you to do that.

But it may not be necessary: You *could* change the `CopyTo` method so that instead of hardcoding all the properties to be copied, it uses reflection to obtain a list of all public properties to copy.

Example code to start with:

```
FieldInfo[] myObjectFields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (FieldInfo fi in myObjectFields)
{
    i.SetValue(destination, fi.GetValue(source));
}
```

---

To handle different property names: You could introduce an attribute which allows you to specify which property of `ThirdPartyEmployee` translates to which property of `Employee`. This can also be evaluated using reflection.

Example:

```
public class Employee
{
    [CopyFromThirdPartyEmployee("F_Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [CopyFromThirdPartyEmployee("L_Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [CopyFromThirdPartyEmployee("Telephone1")]
    public string MobileTelephone { get; set; }
}
```

You could have the `CopyTo` method throw an exception when it finds a public property which does not have the required mapping attribute. That way you could be sure that every property also has the attribute - but that would be a runtime error, not a compile time error.

---

Another approach be to simply make `Employee` a wrapper for `ThirdPartyEmployee`:

```
public class Employee
{
    private ThirdPartyEmployee _baseEmployee;

    public Employee() { _baseEmployee = new ThirdPartyEmployee(); }
    public Employee(ThirdPartyEmployee e) { _baseEmployee = e; }

    public string FirstName 
    { 
        get { return _baseEmployee.F_Name; }
        set { _baseEmployee.F_Name = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

That way you'd notice that if you can't access a property you haven't implemented it. The downside is that every employee would then be based on a `ThirdPartyEmployee`.

Comment: Not so easy when name changes are involved, as appears to be the case here (e.g. `F_Name` -> `FirstName`)

Comment: Names of properties not match each other, at your case better approach - to use AutoMapper.

Comment: Hm, didn't notice the different names actually... I'll still leave this answer as it may still be helpful. Adding possible mapping through attributes.

Comment: The attribute approach is quite good, though I have to say that I can already see someone extending it to allow whatever *conversions* that might need to take place. If the OP only needs a straight map, it looks quite good, though.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenDittmar for answer. Yes, it possible to do it with attributes ... If somebody adds some new property he\she will notice then  attribute should also to be provided ... But is it correct using of attributes ?

Comment: @Disappointed What do you mean by "Is it correct using of attributes"? This is similar to attributes telling the XML serializer whether to serialize something under a different name, etc. I don't see anything wrong with it :-)

Comment: goto say attributes for mapping is ugly as hell

Comment: @Mark In case you downvoted: This may be your personal opinion, but it doesn't make the answer wrong. In case you're not the one who downvoted: Why the downvote?

Comment: To the contrary based on the ops question in what way would these solutions solve the problem of someone forgetting to change ConvertTo method. Surely only a unit test/coupled with reflection can ensure that? Your suggestion to change how they approach the problem is not an answer but just that a suggestion on how to avoid it.

Comment: This answer answers the question because the first sentence contains the information that a compilation error (as requested by the OP) can not be achieved with standard means. The rest of the answer - as you correctly analyzed - gives hints on how to avoid the problem. This seems to be fine to the OP given that he accepted this answer.

Answer (score 4):

If your `Employee` class is just a container, there's one simple approach:

```
public class Employee
{
  private readonly string firstName;

  public Employee(string firstName)
  {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
}
```

Now your conversion method has no choice but to pass all the arguments, so you get a compiler error when the conversion method isn't updated.

Of course, this still isn't foolproof - if you also care about changing the arguments, this doesn't help much.

And now that we have Roslyn, with great integration in Visual Studio, you can actually make your own compiler errors using a Roslyn analyzer. If you're not afraid of getting your hands dirty, this would be a great opportunity to show how useful something like that can be. Sadly, it's not very easy to use right now, and needs "the right kind of thinking" to be wielded well. It will allow you to make rules like "a class conversion extension method must assign all properties in the resulting class", for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the help of reflection, but dictionary for names mapping is needed:

```
public static class ThirdPartyExtensions
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> map;
    static ThirdPartyExtensions()
    {
        map = new Dictionary<string, string>{ {"F_Name", "FirstName"} /*and others*/};
    }  

    public static Employee ConvertTo(this ThirdPartyEmployee thirdPartyEmployee)
    {
        var result = new Employee();

        if(map.Count < typeof(Employee).GetProperties().Count())
            throw new Exception("Forget to add mapping for new field!");

        foreach(var prop in typeof(ThirdPartyEmployee).GetProperties())
            if(map.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
            {
                var temp = typeof(Employee).GetProperty(map[prop.Name]);
                temp.SetValue(result, prop.GetValue(thirdPartyEmployee));
            }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd still have to maintain the dictionary, and you'd have to remember to modify a second source file, so this just shifts the problem. The attribute approach I suggested at least keeps the work to be done to the same source file / class.

Comment: Thanks Slava. But as @ThorstenDittmar said nothing suggest to person who adds new property that some dictionary have to be updated ...

Comment: This fact will be detected with the help of `throw new Exception` when `ConvertTo` method will be called. At @ThorstenDittmar solution you can to not set attribute and all will still work, i.e. code still depends on person's factor.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov ... which would not be a problem if you threw an exception upon finding a public property that does *not* have the required attribute ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar what stop you to do this?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Nothing! You said that my solution runs with or without attributes, but doesn't actually check whether the attribute is given, which your solution does by explicitly checking whether mapping is complete. I just said that the same thing could be easily implemented with the attribute approach :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using Roslyn analyzers it's possible to produce compile-time (and IntelliSense) errors that go beyond the scope of the compiler. Here's a very simple implementation of an analyzer that checks that all the properties of a type returned by a method have been assigned. It doesn't take into account control flow (e.g. `if`).

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class AssignAllPropertiesAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor("AssignAllPropertiesAnalyzer",
        "All properties must be assigned.", "All properties of the return type must be assigned.", "Correctness", 
        DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeMethod, SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeMethod(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var methodNode = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
        var methodSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(methodNode);

        if (methodSymbol.GetReturnTypeAttributes().Any(x => x.AttributeClass.Name == "AssignAllPropertiesAttribute"))
        {
            var properties = methodSymbol.ReturnType.GetMembers().OfType<IPropertySymbol>().Where(x => !x.IsReadOnly).ToList();

            foreach (var assignmentNode in methodNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<AssignmentExpressionSyntax>())
            {
                var propertySymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(assignmentNode.Left).Symbol as IPropertySymbol;
                if (propertySymbol != null)
                {
                    properties.Remove(propertySymbol);
                }
            }

            if (properties.Count > 0)
            {
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, methodSymbol.Locations[0]);
                context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }
    }
```

The analyzer assumes an attribute named `AssignAllProperties` is applied to return type of a method. In the following example, `~~~~~~` marks the location where analyzer would produce a diagnostic.

```
class A
{
    public string S { get; set; }
}

[return: AssignAllProperties]
public static A Create()
                ~~~~~~
{
    return new A();
}
```

An analyzer can be installed both as a VSIX and as a NuGet package. I would recommend always using the NuGet approach - it would apply the analyzer for everyone consuming the code and would allow you to change the severity (e.g. to error), thus failing the compilation. To get started with building an analyzer library, install the [Roslyn SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis) and create an *Analyzer with Code Fix* C# project.

Comment: I just cannot believe that somebody can do so much work for stranger(me in this case.). Your answer inspire me to investigate roslyn and to write some "extension" to it(i will do it in nearest future).Thanks a lot for efforts !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate a compile error for that, but... I would move the conversion method to the `Employee` class. I suggest to avoid Extension methods that are dependend on data *(like properties from other classes)*

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileTelephone { get; set; }

    public static Employee From(ThirdPartyEmployee employee)
    {
        var result = new Employee();

        result.FirstName = thirdPartyEmployee.F_Name;
        result.LastName = thirdPartyEmployee.L_Name;
        result.MobileTelephone = thirdPartyEmployee.Telephone1;

        return result;
    }
}
```

This way you keep all functionality in the right class/file and it is clear for others if they add properties.

Comment: Why should it be the responsibility of the `Employee` class to convert data from another unrelated class? And regardless, you didn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it seems it doesn't solve my problem ...In this case person can just forget to change method in Employee class, not in ThirdPartyExtensions class

Comment: I think putting the responsibility to the class that needs the information, is a better place than moving responsibility to a class that shouldn't be aware of the other class. and `You cannot` was my answer. Or else, he should _generate_ his dal-layer.

Comment: In the OP's design, there's two unrelated classes that each have their business domain, and a single class that brings them together. This is very much in the spirit of OOP, and doesn't create unwelcome dependencies between the two business classes. I have used your approach in the past, but I find that separating conversion methods makes everything a lot easier to reason about and a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: Mapping is not necessarily something that needs to be in the Employee class, I would also keep it in a separate mapping class. It's the same as validation, which is best put in a separate validation class.

Comment: So, as I understand it correctly, you advise to bring the conversion in a separate class. (like a mapper)

Comment: Yes, conversion/mapping is another responsibility (single responsibility pattern). Read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/301580/best-practices-regarding-type-mapping-and-extension-methods